# Which remote communcation type should I use?

Tags: rf, wireless, wifi, xbee, bluetooth-low-energy

In my project I have to give only 4-digit number to each device(50+ devices) without any wire. And there will be only one transmitter for all receivers. Which communcation type should I use?

Frequency of requests will be 10 seconds for every device.
Range will be maximum 150 meters.
And power doesnt important, but 1xAA battery will be great
P.S: Cost is imporant for now

Comment: I know but I can't decide and asking for personal experience.Which one is more stable? WiFi ,simple RF or bluetooth?

Comment: Bluetooth over 150 metres? Really? Simple RF sounds simplest.

Comment: What about WiFi like NRF24L01?

Comment: Yes, nRF24l01+ is a good start, and that *is* an RF transceiver, not WiFi. WiFi would be something like ESP8266.

Comment: Wifi sounds way too complex for what you need. And 150 meters omnidirectional wifi with 1*AA battery seems unrealistic too.

Comment: How about speaker/microphones? I would be very excited to make such system. It would be like an ASCII communication over terminal, but without a terminal or ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

To provide 150 meter coverage, it would be better to use Sub 1 GHz RF modules instead of Bluetooth. I think, TI CC1310 seems like a good start point to handle your problem and comes with simple examples to provide you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So you need a 50-code RF remote control and receiver/decoder. I would start with circuit that uses a Holtek chip, like this: 
http://www.electroschematics.com/8712/rf-based-wireless-remote-control-system/
but to get enough codes, you would need to add an keyboard encoder chip to the transmitter, and keyboard decoder on the receiver circuit.